# Reformat unstructured Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reformatting, unstructured-data

I have to read multiple PDF files via tabula-py.
This works good, it returns a dataframe, or a list of dataframes in case of multiple ranges of interests are set.

The problem is, that the underlying pdf has no structured format:

| index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | **name** |
| 1 | Mr. John Doe |
| 2 | **Address** |
| 3 | 123 Main Street |
| 4 | Anytown |
| 5 | Germany |
| 6 | **Date** |
| 7 | 01.01.2010 |

How could I reformat a Pandas Dataframe to set "name","address" and "date" to resp. columns and set residual entries correctly as values?

| index | name | address_street | address_city | address_state | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mr. John Doe | 123 Main Street | Anytown | Germany | 01.01.2010 |

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I'm understanding the problem correctly: You have a bunch of individual dataframes that look like your first table. That is, a single column (with label `0`), of alternating (key, value) pairs, and therefore always an even number of rows. And you want to combine them into a single table, with a row for each of the original dataframe.

First, some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({0: ['name:', 'Mr. John Doe', 'Address:', '123 Main Street', 'Date', '01.01.2010']})
y = pd.DataFrame({0: ['name:', 'Mr. Freddy Kreuger', 'Address:', '1428 Elm Street', 'Date', '11.09.1984']})
```

We can convert one of these dataframes into a dictionary of key:value pairs using dictionary comprehension:

```
{x[0].values[2*i]: x[0].values[2*i+1] for i in range(int(len(x)/2))}
```

And that results in

```
{'name:': 'Mr. John Doe', 'Address:': '123 Main Street', 'Date': '01.01.2010'}
```

To break down the dictionary comprehension: The general form of this is `{key: value for index in iterable}`. The iterable we're using is the integers up to half the length of `x`. In this case `range(int(len(x)/2))` will be `[0, 1, 2]`. We slice the values of the `0` column of the dataframe `x` with `x[0].values[]`. We use `2*i` for the key and `2*i + 1` for the value, so that the index pairs we use are `(0, 1)`, `(2, 3)` and `(4, 5)`.

Once we have our data in a bunch of dictionaries like that, we can combine them into a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({0: ['name:', 'Mr. John Doe', 'Address:', '123 Main Street', 'Date', '01.01.2010']})
y = pd.DataFrame({0: ['name:', 'Mr. Freddy Kreuger', 'Address:', '1428 Elm Street', 'Date', '11.09.1984']})

raw_dfs = [x, y]

list_of_dicts = [{df[0].values[2*i]: df[0].values[2*i+1] for i in range(int(len(df)/2))}
                 for df in raw_dfs]

final_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

Here I used a list comprehension to collect all those dictionaries into a single list. But if you're iterating through PDF filenames to generate the raw dataframes, maybe you're building this list as you go. The end result is:

```
>>> print(final_df)
                name:         Address:        Date
0        Mr. John Doe  123 Main Street  01.01.2010
1  Mr. Freddy Kreuger  1428 Elm Street  11.09.1984
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. This is almost what I am looking for. There is only a slight difference and sorry that I did not described it precisely in the example. The key value can have multiple rows of values beneath. For example: address as key and values are underneath each other: Street, City, Country.